# Using Everyauth/Passport.js to authenticate with Twitter whilst asking for username/email/password

Tags: express, oauth, twitter-oauth, passport.js, everyauth

I want to create an authentication system whereby the user can "sign up with Twitter", but all this effectively does is authenticate their Twitter account and prefills a registration form with their Twitter username. The user will then be asked to enter an email and password (or an alternative username).

Thus, upon registration, the user has authenticated access to their Twitter account, and the access token can be stored in a database. Later down the line I will use this to access the Twitter API.

Node modules such as `everyauth` and `passport` do a lot of the heavy lifting with OAuth, but they only appear to provide a `findOrCreateUser` method, which doesn't offer a lot of breathing space to do something like what I need to do – that is, redirect to a registration form before registering the user, or if a user is found, just logging them in as per usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick sketch of a possible approach for this:

Note that Passport does not provide a `findOrCreateUser` method.  All database management and record creation is defined by your application (as it should be), Passport simply provides facilities for authentication.

The key to this approach is to simply create an "incomplete" user record in your database, from the profile data given by twitter.  Then, in your application's routes, you can check if the conditions you need are met.  If not, redirect the user to a form where they are prompted to fill out missing details.

```
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    // Create a user object in your database, using the profile data given by
    // Twitter.  It may not yet be a "complete" profile, but that will be handled
    // later.
    return done(null, user);
  }
));

app.get('/auth/twitter',
  passport.authenticate('twitter'));

app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // The user has authenticated with Twitter.  Now check to see if the profile
    // is "complete".  If not, send them down a flow to fill out more details.
    if (req.user.isCompleteProfile()) {
      res.redirect('/home');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/complete-profile');
    }
  });

app.get('/complete-profile', function(req, res) {
  res.render('profile-form', { user: req.user });
});

app.post('/update-profile', function(req, res) {
  // Grab the missing information from the form and update the profile.
  res.redirect('/home');
});
```

Comment: What if I want to pass the Twitter profile data on to where I check if the profile has been completed? I need to do this in order to store the data in the session and then prefill a registration form with these details.

Comment: Another problem I have is Passport sees the user as authenticated even if they have not completed their profile. I've managed to work around this by writing middleware that checks for authentication **and** a completed profile.

Comment: It would be good if I could pass data onto the next function in this way: `done(null, new User({ 'twitter.id': profile.id }), profile)`. Passport appears to allow a third argument but only if the second argument is falsy?

Comment: Call `return done(null, user, profile)`, then `req.authInfo` will be set the the third argument (the profile in this case).  Your approach with middleware to check for complete profile is correct.  Authentication is complete, in the sense that the user proved their identity.  Any further constraints are your app's, and not strictly authentication, so they should be handled by separate middleware.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. When the user completes their profile, they also enter a password, enabling them to use the local strategy if they want to as well. How do you think I should serialize the user? If they haven't completed their profile, I have to serialize the user object, right? They won't have an ID until their profile is finished.

Comment: That's up to you.  Personally, I would just create a user record, ID and all, and serialize just the ID.  That's the simpler approach, in terms of data management, and allows you to change what you consider a "complete" profile entirely in middleware, without having to worry about extra data serialization steps in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Slight clarification. The test "if (req.user.isCompleteProfile())" could be:

> if (req.user.isCompleteProfile)

ie, you create a field 'isCompleteProfile' when you are making the user record in the twitter step, and mark it true or false, depending on what you know of the user

or: it is a call to a function, thus

> if (isCompleteProfile(req))

in this case, you have a separate function which tests the state of the user you have just created/modified, thus:

> function isCompleteProfile(req) { 
>       if (typeof req.user.local.email === "undefined") return false;
>       else return true;
>   }

And, I'd echo the praise for Jared and this marvellous tutorial on authentication in passportjs.