# Forward a PassportJS to a form authentication to add email, password etc

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, twitter, passport.js

So I have followed this [tutorial](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-twitter). I finished the whole series and the application is working fine. However I would like for users who signup using a social network eg. Facebook etc. to be redirected to a seperate form where they can fill their name(s) email etc. Couple of questions.

1. Would I have to change the database schema to allow 'global'(is this the correct term to use?) values for email and name etc. from the facebook/twitter specific stuff. Like so:

   ```
   var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

   email            : String,
   name             : String
   password         : String,

   facebook         : {
       id           : String,
       token        : String,
   },

   twitter          : {
       id           : String,
       token        : String,
       displayName  : String,
       username     : String,
   },

   google           : {
       id           : String,
       token        : String,
   }

   });
   ```

What then would be the correct route? I currently have:

```
        // TWITTER ROUTES
// route for facebook authentication and login
app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));

// handle the callback after twitter has authenticated the user
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback',
passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/signup' }),
function(req, res) {
// The user has authenticated with Twitter.  Now check to see if the profile
// is "complete".  If not, send them down a flow to fill out more details.
if (req.user.isCompleteProfile()) {
  res.redirect('/profile');
} else {
  res.redirect('/complete-profile');
}});

app.get('/complete-profile', function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile-form', { user: req.user });
});

app.post('/update-profile', function(req, res) {
    // Grab the missing info from the form and update the profile.
    res.redirect('/home');
});

// route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

// if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
if (req.isAuthenticated ())
    return next();

// if they arent redirect them to the home page
res.redirect('/');
}
```

I took it from this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864827/using-everyauth-passport-js-to-authenticate-with-twitter-whilst-asking-for-usern/14961403#14961403).

How would I define the function `isCompleteProfile`? Currently I have something like this:

```
function isCompleteProfile(req, res, next) {

// if user has completed profile, carry on
if (req.isComplete ())
    return next();

// if they arent redirect to complete-profile
res.redirect('/complete-profile');
}
```

The first link (to the tutorial) has some suggestions by the author on how to implement this, in the comment section below the article if anyone needs it. However I have mainly been looking at the SO link.

Obviously it is not working (I just copied the earlier function for `isLoggedIn`. Creating views should (hopefully) not be too difficult. So if anyone can shed some light on how I should solve this issue it will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Uknj

PostScript: Is there also potentially an alternative method? Where I do not use a separate function in the route and just redirect them to another page directly? Not sure how I would do this either, so help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See my clarification back on [Using Everyauth/Passport.js to authenticate with Twitter whilst asking for username/email/password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864827/using-everyauth-passport-js-to-authenticate-with-twitter-whilst-asking-for-usern/14961403#14961403) for an explanation as to how to set up the isCompleteProfile test.